# Using two columns in a single bootstrap row, how can I vertically centre the text in one?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3.

I have a series of rows with two columns. The first column displays text and the second column has an image. I want to vertically centre the text in the first column relative to the row it's in so it aligns nicely with the adjacent image.

Example HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h2>Some heading</h2>
            <p>I want all this text centred relative to the image next door</p>            
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6 image">
             <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/cztLHHo.png"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that I'm using the Bootstrap img-responsive class to correctly resize images for mobile devices.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pfmvfL3r/)

What I'm seeing is this:

[image]

What I want to achieve is this:

[image]

I'm sure this is a commonly performed bit of CSS ninja action but I can't find a good example of it. Can anybody help? I would prefer a CSS solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthickj25/v45udhrv/)

i have used the following property in css

```
.row
{
display: flex;
align-items: center; 
}
```